# Microsoft Sapi in Javascript - changing voices

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, sapi

Currently working on an implementation to use SAPI object in javascript to render some text to speech.

I have basic code which works as:

```
VoiceObj = new ActiveXObject("Sapi.SpVoice");
VoiceObj.Speak("hello world");
```

I am now looking at a way to change which voice is getting used for the TTS.  From looking through the SAPI docs online, I have managed to get an object which contains the voices available, and can select them by an index.

```
voices = VoiceObj.GetVoices();
VoiceObj.Voice = voices.Item(1);
console.log(VoiceObj.Voice.GetDescription());
```

This will correctly pulls voices back, and when logged out, will give the name of the voice.  The problem comes when I try and call `.Speak` after making a change to the voice.  The javascript will just throw `Automation server can't create object` error and no speech is heard.

Is this the correct way for changing the voice?  I can not find any other methods available which would achieve this.

Comment: How are you hosting the javascript?  SAPI objects aren't safe for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var voiceObj = new ActiveXObject("Sapi.SpVoice");
//voiceObj.Speak("hello world");
var voices = voiceObj.GetVoices();
var i,n=voices.Count;
var v; //VoiceObj.Voice
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    console.log("Item "+i);
    var v=voices.Item(i);
    console.log(v.GetDescription());
}
```

Comment: When you speak in a specific language, use xml: 
voiceObj.Speak('<voice required="Language=409">Hello two</voice>');
409=EN
407=DE